# Source the Intel 2017 compiler on linux

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, icc, intel-parallel-studio

I'm following [this video tutorial](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/evaluate-ipsxe-professional-linux) for using the Intel compiler, and the first thing to do is to source the compiler. In the video, this is the command:

```
source /opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.0.019/bin/iccvars.sh intel64
```

However, I'm using the 2017 version and the dir tree is different. I found the same file in:

```
source /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.132/linux/bin/iccvars.sh intel64
```

Is this the analogous command, or do I need to do something else?

Comment: Use iccvars.sh from compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.132. The tutorial is simply obsolete (maybe thre is newer one which was not put on top of your search query etc)

Answer (score 0):

The `linux/` subdirectory was added with ICC 17; 16 and below didn't have it.

Yes, they're basically the same.